# Editing the list of JSs loaded in the cart page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart

When I visit my cart page, there are several ajax call in background which are fetching data which are not used in that page.

Is there a way I can revisit the list of JSs loaded only in the cart page?

Answer (score 0):

If using Chrome browser, you can filter the resource on [Network tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/).

One more thing, why you saw several ajax call in the background. This is because Cart Summary used Ui component (the same with Checkout Page) and need to call APIs to get the shipping method and total from the server side.